# Remove values from IDL array

Tags: indexing, data-manipulation, large-data

I have a variable named `wl` which has a value range from 900 to 30000, another variable name `f` is dependent on it. I want to remove values below 1280 from both of these variables.

What I've done is

```
pO = WHERE(wl < 1280)
```

But when I remove them with `remove` it can't remove error since it needs an array of indices to remove and checking the type of `pO` yields `long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time no see. I found the answer to my question with IDL keyword `WHERE`. To select the range of indices to be subtracted from my `wl, f` and `ivar` variables what I did was

```
ii = WHERE(wl LE 1280)
REMOVE, ii, wl, f, iv
```

and tadaah, the values were removed. For values in between you can use

```
jj = WHERE(wl LE 1280 AND wl GE 1200)
REMOVE, jj, wl, f, iv
```

Happy IDLing